# How to pass in user id into foreach loop?

Tags: laravel, authentication, foreach, import, maatwebsite-excel

I'm a novice when it comes to PHP and Laravel and am embarrassed that I haven't figured this out yet. I'm trying to provide an option for my user to import their database into the application. However, I need to attach a user id to each row so it can be saved with that user. I've tried multiple attempts to grab that user id and pass it into the foreach loop so it can be saved. Any guidance I can receive, I'd be most grateful. I am using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel facade.

Here is my Controller:

```
class ImportController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function importExcel()
    {
        if(Input::hasFile('import_file')){
            $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
            })->get();
            if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $user = Auth::user();
                    $data['user_id'] = $user->id;
                    $insert[] = [
                        'user_id' => $value->user_id,
                        'first_name' => $value->first_name,
                        'last_name' => $value->last_name,
                        'title' => $value->title,
                        'level' => $value->level,
                        'company' => $value->company,
                        'email' => $value->email,
                        'address_1' => $value->address_1,
                        'address_2' => $value->address_2,
                        'city' => $value->city,
                        'state' => $value->state,
                        'zip_code' => $value->zip_code,
                        'office_tel' => $value->office_tel,
                        'mobile_tel' => $value->mobile_tel,
                        'member_since'=> $value->member_since
                    ];
                }
                if(!empty($insert)){
                    DB::table('members')->insert($insert);
                    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Database successfully   imported!');
                }
            }
        }
        return back();
    }
}
```

Here is my route:

```
 Route::post('importExcel', 'ImportController@importExcel');
```

Here is my view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#importExcel">Import</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="importExcel" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="importExcelLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Import Your Database</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Click browse to import your database. Only Microsoft Excel extensions are acceptable. Please label your columns as follows:</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>user_id (leave this column empty)</li>
                        <li>first_name</li>
                        <li>last_name</li>
                        <li>title</li>
                        <li>level</li>
                        <li>company</li>
                        <li>address_1</li>
                        <li>address_2</li>
                        <li>city</li>
                        <li>state</li>
                        <li>zip_code</li>
                        <li>office_tel</li>
                        <li>mobile_tel</li>
                        <li>member_since</li>
                    </ul>

                <form action="{{ URL::to('importExcel') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="import_file" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Import File</button>
                </form>
            </div><!-- /.modal-body-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div><!-- /.modal-footer-->
        </div><!-- /.modal-content-->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog-->
</div><!-- /.modal-->
```

Here is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'title',
        'level',
        'company',
        'email',
        'address_1',
        'address_2',
        'city',
        'state',
        'zip_code',
        'office_tel',
        'mobile_tel',
        'member_since' ];

}
```

Comment: Set the `user_id` in your controller to `$user->id` and not to `$value->user_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Where do you set `$insert`? You have to set this variable with the data you like to import. Despite of that you can try the following:

If I understand you right, the database-field `user_id` should contain the ID of the logged in user - if so, try in your controller the following in `importExcel` (see comment):

```
public function importExcel(Request $request)
    {
        if(Input::hasFile('import_file')){
            $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
            })->get();
            if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $user = Auth::user();
                    $data['user_id'] = $user->id;
                    [
                        'user_id' => $user->id, // Access here the userId of the logged in user
                        'first_name' => $value->first_name,
                        'last_name' => $value->last_name,
                        'title' => $value->title,
                        'level' => $value->level,
                        'company' => $value->company,
                        'email' => $value->email,
                        'address_1' => $value->address_1,
                        'address_2' => $value->address_2,
                        'city' => $value->city,
                        'state' => $value->state,
                        'zip_code' => $value->zip_code,
                        'office_tel' => $value->office_tel,
                        'mobile_tel' => $value->mobile_tel,
                        'member_since'=> $value->member_since
                    ];
                }
                if(!empty($insert)){
                    DB::table('members')->insert($insert);
                    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Database successfully   imported!');
                }
            }
        }
        return back();
    }
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi Andreas! Yes this has definitely helped! Sorry I just realized that I have accidentally deleted the $insert[] that was set for the data to be imported when I was formatting the code on here. I'm going to make that edit right now.

Comment: Fine :) Glad that I could help - good luck for your project :)